# Why does PhotonNetwork GetCustomRoomList fail after several connections?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I'm trying to create a custom lobby, and have players randomly fill rooms that have maxPlayers=2, the first 2 players connect and join a room but when the third player connects and calls GetCustomRoomList I get this error:

GetGameList failed: OperationResponse 217: ReturnCode: -2 (SQL logic error or missing database near "LIMIT": syntax error). Parameters: {}

What I'm doing is first attempting to join a random room inside that custom lobby, and if that fails, create a new room.

I start connecting like this:

```
TypedLobby lobbyData = new TypedLobby ("Proto01Lobby", LobbyType.SqlLobby);

PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = GAME_VERSION;
PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings ();
```

Then I try to join the random room:

```
public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
   Debug.Log ("Connetected!");
   PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom (null, 2, MatchmakingMode.FillRoom, lobbyData, null, null);
}
```

IF that fails I try to get the list of rooms, to then create a unique room name based on the amount of rooms in the lobby:

```
public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
   Debug.Log ("Failed to connect to random room, Create a New Room");
   PhotonNetwork.GetCustomRoomList (lobbyData, null);
}

public override void OnRoomListUpdate (List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
   Debug.Log ("Amount of rooms in lobbby: "+roomList.Count);
   string roomName = "CanvasProto" + roomList.Count;
   Debug.Log ("Create room: "+roomName);

   RoomOptions options = new RoomOptions ();
   options.MaxPlayers = 2;
   PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(roomName, options, lobbyData, null);
}
```

But when the third player connects, he/she never reaches the OnRoomListUpdate because for some reason it fails.

Answer (score -1):

GetCustomRoomList fails because its trying to run an SQL query with null.

You need to add a query that filters the rooms you are trying to fetch.

If you want all rooms use GetRoomList().

I should warn you, if 2 players are in one room and 2 new players try to join, both will see that they need to create a new room and you my have to clients trying to create 2 rooms with the same name at the same time.

You will also not reuse room names for games that have finished.

Comment: Thanks. I don't see a static method for PhotonNetwork.GetRoomList() though... Using version 2.7. Also, from what you are saying, it's better to create a random name then I guess, right?

Comment: I also noticed that the first user that connects, does actually call GetCustomRoomList passing an SQL query as null, perhaps it doesn't fail because there aren't any rooms yet?

Comment: @user2000950 `GetRoomList` was removed in PUN2. You can find this info and others in the PUN1 to PUN2's "[Migration Notes](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/pun/current/getting-started/migration-notes)".